# Can't Import packaged class files from a jar in jython when it contains classes in the default package

Tags: java, jython-2.7

I am working on a program that needs to import a jar that has classes both in the default package (root of the jar) and in packages.
So far I have this code and it works so i can import the ones in default but it fails when trying to import ones on packages.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + "/versions/1.7.2.jar")
```

If I run import a (a is a class as this is a Obfuscated jar.)
it imports but if I run import net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer it does not work it says No Module named net.

Which I know the class and all packages around it is there so any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **Jython** does not correctly find the code.

The source code is based on files like `a.class` wich you can import but not `net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer`.

Comment: net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer is a valid class in the file. (Its used to launch the server from the JVM)